# How to save dynamic number of images using carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, dynamic-data

I'm using gem `Carrierwave` with `fog` to upload my images to `AWS S3`.

Right now, I have static memories like this.

```
class CreateImagePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :image_posts do |t|
      t.string :img1
      t.string :img2
      t.string :img3
      t.string :img4
      t.string :img5
      t.string :img6
      t.string :img7
      t.string :img8

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

But I want to make it possible to upload dynamic numbers of images not like present setting(limited in number of images).

My model looks like this.

```
class ImagePost < ActiveRecord::Base   

    mount_uploader :img1, S3uploaderUploader
    mount_uploader :img2, S3uploaderUploader
    mount_uploader :img3, S3uploaderUploader
    mount_uploader :img4, S3uploaderUploader
    mount_uploader :img5, S3uploaderUploader
    mount_uploader :img6, S3uploaderUploader
    mount_uploader :img7, S3uploaderUploader
    mount_uploader :img8, S3uploaderUploader

end
```

Any suggestions or documents that I can read? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create model `Attachment` with `has_many` relation:

```
class ImagePost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attachments
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image_post
  mount_uploader :img, S3uploaderUploader
end
```

Migrations:

```
class CreateAttachments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :attachments do |t|
      t.integer :image_post_id
      t.string :img
    end
    add_index :attachments, :image_post_id
  end
end
```

Now you can create any number of images:

```
image_post = ImagePost.create
images.each do |image|
  image_post.attachments.create(img: image)
end
```

Comment: It's really nice solution to me. Then, I don't need to have any table cells for the images on `ImagePost`?

Comment: @ChangnamHong No, you don't. You need them in `Attachment` only.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that.